# Safari Block Formatting Context Margin Issue

Tags: html, css, safari

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 3em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.right  {
  background-color: #ff7f50;
  margin-left: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

This works as expected in Chrome. `left` covers 30% of width. Block Formatting Context comes into action because of `overflow:hidden` and there is a 10% gap between `left` and `right` blocks.

But in Safari, this isn't working. There is no 10% gap.

However, when `overflow:hidden` is commented out, then it seems to work.

How can I get Block Formatting Context to work consistently across these two browsers ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbgVgP (Open `this` stackoverflow page or codepen.io page in both Chrome and Safari).

Comment: Which version of Safari? ...and on what OS?

Comment: I'm using Safari Version 7.0.2 (9537.74.9) on Mac OS X Version 10.9.2

Comment: Tested it for Safari (5.1.7) on Windows 8.1 - same problem